# How to cite references

Tags: biblatex

I am writing my PhD dissertation in LaTeX and want to include a bibliography, obviously. However, I'm having problems making this work at all. Instead of trying to make it work in my multiple dissertation LaTeX files, I made a minimum working example of it, but not even that works! Can anybody please help me with telling me what I'm doing wrong? I want an author year citation style, by the way. No numbers, just citations of author year in the text and a reference list sorted alphabetically at the end.

This is my minimum working example, `example.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a test \cite{bakerstair}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here's the content of my `library.bib` file:

```
@Article{bakerstair,
  author = {Baker, Doran J. and Stair, A. T.},
  title = {Rocket measurements of the altitude distributions of the hydroxyl airglow},
  journal = {Physica Scripta},
  year = {1988},
  volume = {37},
  pages = {611-622},
}
```

Error messages I get after running PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX(x2) + View Pdf in TeXMaker:

> ```
> example.tex. Warning. line 9. Citation 'bakerstair' on page 1 undefined.
> example.tex. Warning. line 11. Empty bibliography.
> example.tex. Warning. line 1. There were undefined references.
> example.tex. Warning. line 1. Please (re)run Biber on the file: example and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
> ```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your editor probably doesn't run Biber for you, but BibTeX. Please check [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for detailed instructions on how to make your editor run Biber.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! You are rigth, TeXMaker didn't run Biber. I have now followed the instructions in the link, but I still get an error: "ERROR - Cannot find control file 'example.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX? INFO -ERRORS:1.! How do I pass the backend=biber option to BibLaTeX?

Comment: In your MWE you already have `backend=biber`, so that should be OK. Do you maybe have the "use a 'build' subdirectory" option enabled? Can you find any temporary files in the directory (`.aux`, `.bcf`, `.log`, ...)

Comment: Yes, I had the "build subdirectory" option enabled. Now I've disabled it, but I got new error messages in addtion to the ones I've already seen before: ! Use of \sortlist doesn't match its definition. \sortlist{
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \sortlist{anyt}
! Undefined control sequence.\entry ...ata@\the \c@refsection @\blx@slist@name@\abx@field@entrykey }\csu... \entry{bakerstair}{article}{}
! Undefined control sequence.<argument> ...equal \expandafter {\blx@slist@type}{entry} {\listcsxadd {blx... \endentry
etc...

Comment: Delete the temporary files and make sure that the Biber and `biblatex` versions match. (Check the biblatex or Biber doc for a table of compatible versions.)

Comment: I'm sorry for my stupid questions, but how do I check which versions of Biber and biblatex I've got?

Comment: If you add `\listfiles` to the very top of your file you can check the `biblatex` version in the `.log` file after a compilation. The Biber version can be found in the `.blg` file. (You can also just do an update to make sure the versions match.)